# Date Input Format Issue in Safari on iOS Devices

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, datepicker, calendar

I'm encountering an issue with Safari on iOS devices related to the input type 'date'. When using an input field of type date, Safari's default behavior is to display a calendar picker where the date format is shown as dd-mmm-yyyy (e.g., 20-Dec-2023). However, I need the input to accept dates in the format dd/mm/yyyy.

I've attempted to address this problem by using placeholders and patterns without success. The desired format works perfectly in other web browsers, including Safari on desktop. Is there a specific workaround or a different approach to ensure the input date format (dd/mm/yyyy) is recognized correctly on Safari for iOS devices?

Any insights, suggestions, or alternative solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Here's an example of what I've tried so far:

input type="date" pattern="\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"